# Dark heroic fantasy cartoon from the 90s with a worm floating in a glass jar

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Not much I remember, however a specific scene should be enough.

I vaguely remember a surprisingly dark saturday morning cartoon, maybe with furry knights, one scene that really impressed me was one where they fight a kind of mech/ golem with a sort of demon/ worm encased in glass piloting it. The glass was somewhat self healing but eventually it breaks and the worm slithers out. It might have been an animated movie as these were sometimes chopped to be aired as episodes.